# How do I different color each edge for polygon star in Coreldraw CC6?

Tags: polygon, coreldraw

I want to do different color edges in polygon star. How do I this? I prepared easy sample for you in Print. That's here :

http://i.hizliresim.com/LpGmYj.png

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but what if you convert the star to curves, break the curve apart and color each side separately? Then you could group the separate curves to move/scale them together.